# can someone give me an idea how to extract information for text such as invoice bills using natural language processing

Tags: nlp

suppose i have text file with invoice details in it . I want to extract only some information based on my certain condition such as Mobile - 25,000 and quantity - 1 i want to extract only mobile and quantity based information and store it in text file.Can someone give me an idea how to do this.

Comment: i have .txt file which i need to extract information .

Comment: i know that it can be done using information extraction techniques in NLP how to do it i dont know can someone specify the link here.

Comment: NLP is using a sledgehammer to squash a fly in this case. Use regex as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for regex. With this you can parse the text based on your specified search patterns.

Some info:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

With python you can follow this documentation in order to build your regex expressions:
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html